# How to resolve "org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Unable to create resource" error in AEM6.1?

Tags: java, aem

I am getting this error in our production environment-

```
*ERROR* [10.49.33.40 [1498065304267] POST /content/mywebsite/en/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Unable to create resource named autodiscover.xml in /content/mywebsite/en/autodiscover
21.06.2017 13:15:04.270 *ERROR* [10.49.33.40 [1498065304267] POST /content/mywebsite/en/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing.
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No default node type available for /content/mywebsite/en/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
                at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.util.TreeUtil.addChild(TreeUtil.java:186)
                at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.NodeDelegate.addChild(NodeDelegate.java:692)
                at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$5.perform(NodeImpl.java:296)
                at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$5.perform(NodeImpl.java:262)
                at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:200)
                at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:112)
                at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:262)
                at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:247)
                at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.create(JcrResourceProvider.java:567)
                at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.tree.ResourceProviderEntry.create(ResourceProviderEntry.java:502)
                at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.create(ResourceResolverImpl.java:1132)
                at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.AbstractCreateOperation.deepGetOrCreateNode(AbstractCreateOperation.java:584)
                at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.AbstractCreateOperation.processCreate(AbstractCreateOperation.java:107)
                at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation.doRun(ModifyOperation.java:91)
                at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.AbstractPostOperation.run(AbstractPostOperation.java:92)
                at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.SlingPostServlet.doPost(SlingPostServlet.java:202)
                at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:149)
                at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:345)
                at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:376)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:547)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:371)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:171)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
                at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:155)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
                at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:137)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:201)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:181)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:292)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:240)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.analytics.provisioning.impl.UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilter(UserAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:119)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:95)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:269)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
                at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:132)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:84)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:217)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:336)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
                at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
                at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
                at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
                at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
                at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
                at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
                at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But we don't have "/content/mywebsite/en/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml" or "/content/mywebsite/en/autodiscover" in our repository. Not sure from where it's taking this url.

How can I debug it without going to this particular URL. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a badly configured email app is trying to connect to your website to download account discovery settings. Post should not be allowed on that path on production btw.

Comment: How can I resolve/debug this?

Comment: Check you dispatcher config and block post action on your site globally and allow for specific paths only.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your stack trace, one thing that stands out is:

`/content/mywebsite/`

This looks like some default config in your dispatcher files which may be redirecting requests from your domain (wwww.example.com) to a default (assumed) content structure on your publisher.

OR, it could be a sling mapping in your publisher.

So, on explanation as suggested in comments is that some email client (like Outlook) is trying to auto register a user with email address corresponding to your domain (user@example.com). This will initiate an auto-discover POST request.

This is a normal setup for most email clients in corporate environment so it's not an issue. The problems that are worth considering over here are:

> Your publisher is accepting **POST** requests from anonymous users. This must be blocked by dispatcher or publisher.

Adobe has lot of documentation on dispatcher setup and publisher security to fix this issue. Is summary, you need to disable write permissions for anonymous users on publisher and configure dispatcher to block POST requests on arbitrary paths.

> Debugging

You can easily reproduce this issue on local environment by using curl to simulate the same POST request. .xml files are not allowed under /content node which throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, you don't need to debug this issue as it is network and security configuration problem rather than AEM issue. You must:

- Secure anonymous POST on your publisher and dispatcher.
- Fix your sling mappings or dispatcher configs (if any) to take care of mywebsite content path resolution.

Another possibility is that some internal corporate network configuration is wrong and SMTP auto discovery is now redirected to your publisher rather than your usual mail server.